# Use urllib.urlopen or requests.get to get data from Flask Server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I have a Flask Server running and tried to request data like this:

```py
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:5000')
# HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('http://my.ip.address:5000')
# HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

import requests
requests.get("http://localhost:5000")
# <Response [403]>
```

This is my flask dummy code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def route_index():
    return 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Are there certain settings I need to apply on the Flask server side to allow requests like this? Or are there parameters that I need to set in `urlopen` or `requests.get` to correctly retrieve the data?

Comment: Have you tried to open the URL http://localhost:5000 in a browser when your server is running? What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem were seemingly the proxy settings of my organisation.

Using https://pypi.org/project/pypac it is all working:

```py
from pypac import PACSession
session = PACSession()
session.get('http://localhost:5000')
# <Response [200]>
```